# Какое влияние на форму дуги оказывают атрибуты Elliptical Arc

Tags: вёрстка, svg, svg-animation

```html
<svg width='1700' height='500' style='border:1px solid black' viewBox='0 0 400 400'>
   <path d='M30,50 A100,80 10 0 0 150,50'/>
</svg>
```

1. Почему при A100,80 получается маленький круг

```html
<svg width='1700' height='500' style='border:1px solid black' viewBox='0 0 400 400'>
   <path d='M30,50 A50,80 10 0 0 150,50'/>
</svg>
```

1. при A50,80 получается большой круг ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684885/arc-svg-parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По шагам

По этому принципу я сделал эту анимацию

```html
<svg viewBox="-10 -10 520 520" width="500">
  <defs>
    <style>
      path {
        fill: none;
        stroke: red;
        stroke-width: 2;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0,100 A200,300 0,0,1 250,100 M0,100 A200,150 0,0,0 250,100">
    <animate attributeName="d" dur="3s" values="M0,100 A200,330 0,0,1 250,100 M0,100 A200,200 0,0,0 250,100;
                     M0,100 A200,300 0,0,1 250,100 M0,100 A200,200 0,0,0 250,100;
                     M0,100 A200,300 0,0,1 250,100 M0,100 A200,150 0,0,0 250,100" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
  <g transform="translate(0,10)">
    <circle cx="130" cy="80" r="40" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="130" cy="80" r="16" fill="darkred" />
    <circle cx="130" cy="80" r="6" fill="red" />

    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" values="-20 4; -10 2; 0 2; 10 2; 20 4" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Арка начинается всегда с команды `M` то есть установить перо в координаты

Я для примера выбрал viewBox в котором будет легко считать

Начало арки будет здесь : M0,250 а конец арки будет здесь A100,100

Все остальные команды лишние но расскажу и о них тоже

В арке семь (7) команд и каждая выполняет свою роль

Про начало и конец арки я уже рассказал дальше 6, 7 это диаметр и диаметр/2 **это если речь именно о том как нарисовать круг на path**

Первый пример

```html
<svg viewBox="-10 -10 520 520" width="500">
  <defs>
    <style>
      path{
        fill: none;
        stroke: red;
        stroke-width: 2;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0,250 A100,100 0,0,1 500,250" />
  <path d="M0,250 A100,100 0,0,0 500,250" />
</svg>
```

Для того что бы не было двух path а был один мы объеденим их вот так

`<path d="M0,250 A100,100 0,0,1 500,250 M0,250 A100,100 0,0,0 500,250" />`

Если разбирать ещё подробнее то из `A` или точнее самой этой командой обычно делают чарты ...

3 и 4 позицией ни когда не пользовался

5 позиция в A это по какому направлению рисовать арку по часовой или против часовой - всего два значения 0 или 1

И кстати когда пишут руками две арки таким образом то закрывать path не надо

Comment: <path d="M0,220 A10,70 0,0,1 500,250" /> почему у меня дуга увеличивается я ведь уменьшил число?

Comment: @Leks по факту ты рисуешь два эллипса но один скрывает другой - как бы делает clipPath типа того ..и когда и уменьшаешь то вторая арка отодвигается влево/вправо - и в этом случае ты видишь или большую часть видимого эллипса или меньшую часть в случае увеличения числа - примерное поведение [видно на снимке экрана](https://ibb.co/zPyd7DT) команда A или Arc это вообще самое сложное что есть в SVG трудно объяснить

Comment: @Leks уменьшать или увеличить для тебя и меня это разные вещи - к примеру - все координаты svg начинаются в верхнего левого угла - и когда ты уменьшаешь то на самом деле ты увеличиваешь - то есть тот самый нижний arc поднимиться на верх то есть так и получится что ты увидешь большую часть хотя саму цифру ту уменьшил но арка поднялась выше

Comment: @Leks https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/VweLymR - вот в этом примере где два circle - попробуй уменьши у верхнего circle - cx или cy в арке тот же принцип -

Comment: Вы рисуете path через редактор ?

Comment: @Leks нет....руками и только руками

Answer (score 4):

**Немного теории**

> `<path d='M30,50 A100,80 10 0 0 150,50'/>`

Это формула `path` называется - [Дуга элипса – Elliptical Arc (A,a)](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=900#comm_a)

Каждый параметр выполняет своё назначение:

**M mx,my** – координаты начальной точки дуги эллипса

**A rx,ry** – радиусы дуги эллипса

**x-axis-rotation** – угол поворота всей дуги эллипса относительно оси абцисс. В примере 10 градусов.

**large-arc-flag** – параметр, отвечающий за вывод бОльшей части дуги, если `flag =1` или меньшей  части дуги при `flag=0` см. рисунок ниже.

**sweep-flag** – отвечает за направление отрисовки дуги из начальной точки в конечную точку. Если `sweep-flag=1`, то дуга эллипса будет отрисована по `часовой стрелке`. При `sweep-flag=0` – против часовой стрелки.

**x,y** – координаты конечной точки дуги эллипса

На рисунке из [спецификации W3C path](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) видно, что дуга Elliptical Arc получается в результате взаимодействия двух одинаковых эллипсов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для формулы `<path d='M30,50 A100,80 10 0 0 150,50'/>`

**Имеем:**

1. `large-arc-flag = 0` - рисуется меньшая часть дуги от точки `Arc start` до точки `Arc end`
   `sweep-flag= 0` - отрисовка малой дуги идёт против часовой стрелки

Это первый фрагмент рисунка (вверху слева)

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border:1px solid black' viewBox='0 0 400 400'>
   <path fill="gold" stroke="red" d='M30,50 A100,80 10 0 0 150,50'/>
</svg>
```

4. `large-arc-flag = 1` - рисуется бОльшая часть дуги от точки `Arc start` до точки `Arc end`
   `sweep-flag= 1` - отрисовка бОльшой дуги идёт по часовой стрелки

(нижний, правый фрагмент рисунка)

```html
    <svg width='400' height='400' style='border:1px solid black' viewBox='0 0 400 400'>
       <path fill="gold" stroke="red" d='M30,50 A100,80 10 1 1 150,50'/>
    </svg>
```

Все параметры формулы **Elliptical Arc** взаимосвязаны, поэтому увеличение одного параметра, например радиусов может, как увеличивать, так и уменьшать результирующую дугу.  Всё зависит и от других параметров тоже.

**UPDATE**

На практике широкое распространение получил частный случай **Eliptical Arc**, когда радиусы равны, допустим 50px - `A50,50`
так как при использовании circle, в качестве трассы движения анимированного объекта,  не работает `аnimateMotion` Этот вид анимации работает только с трассой нарисованной `path`

Поэтому берутся две дуги, которые зеркальны, образуя тем самым полный круг.

Одна дуга рисуется по часовой стрелке `sweep-flag = 1`

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border:1px solid black' viewBox='0 0 400 400'>
       <path fill="gold" stroke="red" d='M110,150 A50,50 10 1 1 210,150'/>
 </svg>
```

зеркальная дуга против часовой стрелки  `sweep-flag = 0`

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border:1px solid black' viewBox='0 0 400 400'>
       <path fill="gold" stroke="red" d='M110,150 A50,50 10 1 0 210,150'/>
 </svg>
```

Обе дуги вместе:

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border:1px solid black' viewBox='0 0 400 400'>
       <path fill="gold" stroke="red"
          d='
           M110,150 A50,50 10 1 1 210,150
           M110,150 A50,50 10 1 0 210,150'/>
 </svg>
```

Comment: Elliptical Arc образует 2 эллипса которые накладываются частично друг на друга от настроек зависит  какой эллипс (один)  увидим так ?

Comment: @Leks вернее не эллипс, а то что от него останется в результате взаимодействия с другим эллипсом

Comment: На картинке видно что два эллипса частично накладываются друг на друга а как сразу узнать какой ширины и высоты будет занимать частичное наложение ?

Comment: @Leks если точно нужно узнать размеры, то по математическим формулам. [Например вот так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47695091/7394871) На практике используется обычно частный случай, когда радиусы равны, это полуокружность `A50,50` или окружность с двумя зеркальными дугами  Сейчас добавлю в ответ

Comment: тогда проще просто проверить чем это вычислять :))

Comment: взять конечную ширину и высоту эллипса разделить на 2 отсюда и будет начинаться второй эллипс верно ?

Comment: @Leks да, при равенстве радиусов.

Answer (score 4):

### Примеры анимации атрибутов Elliptical Arc

1. Изменение координаты `Mx` стартовой точки дуги

```
      values="
             M25,200 A50,80 0 1 1 180,200;
             M100,200 A50,80 0 1 1  180,200"
```

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border:1px solid black' viewBox='0 0 400 400'>
       <path fill="gold" stroke="red" d='M30,50 A100,80 10 1 1 150,50'>
         <animate attributeName="d"
           dur="6s"
           calcMode="linear"
           values="
             M25,200 A50,80 0 1 1 180,200;
             M100,200 A50,80 0 1 1  180,200"
             fill="freeze"
             repeatCount="1" /> 
       </path>
    </svg>
```

2. Изменение `sweep-flag` `1 - 0` дуга сначала рисуется по часовой  = `1`, затем против часовой стрелки = `0` Изменение происходит дискретно из одного состояния в другое

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border:1px solid black' viewBox='0 0 400 400'>
       <path fill="gold" stroke="red" d='M30,50 A100,80 10 1 1 150,50'>
         <animate attributeName="d"
           dur="2s"
           calcMode="discrete"
           values="
             M100,200 A50,80 10 1 1 180,200;
             M100,200 A50,80 10 1 0  180,200"
             fill="freeze"
             repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
       </path>
    </svg>
```

3.
`values=" M100,200 A50,80 10 0 0 180,200; M100,200 A50,80 10 1 1  180,200"`

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border:1px solid black' viewBox='0 0 400 400'>
       <path fill="gold" stroke="red" d='M30,50 A100,80 10 1 1 150,50'>
         <animate attributeName="d"
           dur="2s"
           calcMode="discrete"
           values="
             M100,200 A50,80 10 0 0 180,200;
             M100,200 A50,80 10 1 1  180,200"
             fill="freeze"
             repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
       </path>
    </svg>
```

4. Изменение угла наклона кривой **x-axis-rotation**.
   Значение в градусах можно менять линейно

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border:1px solid black' viewBox='0 0 400 400'>
       <path fill="gold" stroke="red" d='M30,50 A100,80 10 1 1 150,50'>
         <animate attributeName="d"
           dur="6s"
           calcMode="linear"
           values="
             M100,200 A50,80 0 1 1 180,200;
             M100,200 A50,80 360 1 1  180,200;
             M100,200 A50,80 360 1 1  180,200;
             M100,200 A50,80 0 1 1 180,200;
             M100,200 A50,80 0 1 1 180,200"
             fill="freeze"
             repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
       </path>
    </svg>
```